# UINavigationController subclass - customizing Pop

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, interface-builder, subclass

Like many others, I would like to perform an action when the 'back' button is used in a UINavigationController.  I am aware of some alternative approaches to this, such as adding my own button and trying to spoof the look, using viewWillDisappear and setting tags on all non-back actions that will cause the view do disappear, etc.

But the one that I would like to try is subclassing UINavigationController and injecting something in popViewControllerAnimated:

But I can't get a simple test case to work.  Here is what I tried...

I created a new class, CustomNavigationController, which inherits from UINavigationController.  In here, I updated popViewControllerAnimated:

.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomNavigationController : UINavigationController

@end
```

.m:

```
#import "CustomNavigationController.h"

@interface CustomNavigationController ()

@end

@implementation CustomNavigationController

- (UIViewController *)popViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated{
    NSLog(@"pop!");
    return [super popViewControllerAnimated:animated];
}

@end
```

In interface builder, I changed the class of the navigation controller:
[image]

What am I missing?  I am expecting 'pop' to be logged whenever I pop any view within this nav controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just tested the very same implementation on iPhone 5.1 simulator and it works fine - it seems the problem is somewhere else.

I've created an empty project from a single-view application template and added CustomNavigationController class with the code which you posted in the question body. An UIButton is used to push another view controller to navigation stack (using storyboard's segue), and 'POP' message is being posted in the console as expected.

[image]

Comment: Thanks - I just confirmed the same in a test project as well. I'll try to track it down elsewhere

Answer (score 1):

From the first paragraph of the documentation on [UINavigationController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

> The UINavigationController class implements a specialized view
>   controller that manages the navigation of hierarchical content. This
>   class is not intended for subclassing. Instead, you use instances of
>   it as-is in situations where you want your application’s user
>   interface to reflect the hierarchical nature of your content.

If you want this kind of customization you're better off implementing your own navigation style controller.

Comment: I too have read this.  I'm just experimenting at the moment. Anyway, 'not intended' strikes me as a soft warning rather than a prohibition.  It doesn't say 'you shouldn't because...'.

I also think my own navigation style controller just to log 'pop' might be overkill (translation: wouldn't know where to start).

Comment: Apple's documentation on UINavigationController now states: "This class is generally used as-is but may be subclassed in iOS 6 and later."