# Change one viewcontroller to landscape only in ios6

Tags: ios6, uinavigationcontroller, rotation, landscape

I've found what appears to be the answer to my question here:

[iOS 6: How do I restrict some views to portrait and allow others to rotate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12630359/ios-6-how-do-i-restrict-some-views-to-portrait-and-allow-others-to-rotate?rq=1)

BUT i don't understand the answer. I'm confused as to where i'm supposed to be putting the code for the UINavigationController. It can't be in the UINavigationController.h file because thats locked. Someone please help

Layth

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting the code in the `UINavigationController.h`, you should create a new class called *MainNavigationController* and inherit `UINavigationController`.

You can then add a Boolean in the new class called *landscapeOK*, and then make your `ViewController` inherit from *MainNavigationController* instead of `UINavigationController`.

Comment: How do make it inherit?  Do I use the code '#import UINavigationController.h' at the top of MainNavigationController?

Comment: And how do i make my viewcontroller inherit from MainNavigationController instead of UINavigationController?

Comment: Please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10109480/uinavigationcontroller-subclass-customizing-pop

Answer (score 0):

**Use this in View did load set direction**

```
 UIViewController *c = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
    [self presentModalViewController:c animated:NO];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```